# Replacing the string + using gsub in R

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

This is my `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = as.character(c("AB+CD+EF", "GH+IJ+KL")), x = c(1,2)
)
df
         a x
1 AB+CD+EF 1
2 GH+IJ+KL 2
```

When I replace the string `"+"` by `">"` using `gsub` it places `">"` between every string:

```
df$y <- gsub("+", ">", df$a)
df
         a x                 y
1 AB+CD+EF 1 >A>B>+>C>D>+>E>F>
2 GH+IJ+KL 2 >G>H>+>I>J>+>K>L>
```

Why does this happen?

Desired output:

```
         a x        y
1 AB+CD+EF 1 AB>CD>EF
2 GH+IJ+KL 2 GH>IJ>KL
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `fixed = TRUE` in gsub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable `fixed = TRUE`

```
> transform(df, y = gsub("+", ">", a, fixed = TRUE))
         a x        y
1 AB+CD+EF 1 AB>CD>EF
2 GH+IJ+KL 2 GH>IJ>KL
```

or use `chartr` instead

```
> transform(df, y = chartr("+", ">", a))
         a x        y
1 AB+CD+EF 1 AB>CD>EF
2 GH+IJ+KL 2 GH>IJ>KL
```